# load() function not working on live server but working on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm creating a chat application where chats are displayed from separate file and refreshed at some interval.

This code works perfectly on local host but not on live server. I've checked many similar problem responses but none sorts me out. Someone kindly help. NB. `alert("abc");` works well on live server

The load function is expected to display contents of `load2.php` file

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
setInterval(
function() {
  // alert("abc");
  $('#content').load('load2.php');
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `load` tag. Please read the wiki before actually tagging it.

Comment: The alert will block execution. If it does not work on live server, look in the console and network tab for issues